# Terraform getting error while using module outputs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My Project structure:

1. modules/s3/main.tf&variables.tf
2. dev/s3/main.tf
3. stage/s3/main.tf
4. main.tf
5. tests/s3_test.go

modules/s3/main.tf:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_s3" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_env_name}-tf-s3-1"
}

output "tf_s3_name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.tf_s3
}
```

modules/s3/variables.tf:

```
variable "bucket_env_name" {
  description = "The name to use for all the cluster resources"
  type        = string
}
```

dev/s3/main.tf:

```
module "Devs3Create" {
  source = "../../modules/s3"
  
  bucket_env_name = "dev"
}
```

stage/s3/main.tf:

```
module "Stages3Create" {
  source = "../../modules/s3"
  
  bucket_env_name = "stage"
}
```

main.tf:

```
module "dev" {
  source = "./dev/s3"
}

module "stage" {
  source = "./stage/s3"
}
```

tests/s3_test.go:

```
package test

import (
    "testing"
    "regexp"

    "github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)


//func Regexp(t TestingT, rx interface{}, str interface{}, msgAndArgs ...interface{}) bool

func TestS3(t *testing.T) {
    // retryable errors in terraform testing.
    terraformOptions := terraform.WithDefaultRetryableErrors(t, &terraform.Options{
        TerraformDir: "../",
    })

    defer terraform.Destroy(t, terraformOptions)

    terraform.InitAndApply(t, terraformOptions)

    output := terraform.Output(t, terraformOptions, "tf_s3_name")
    assert.Regexp(t,regexp.MustCompile("test"), output)
}
```

**Terraform Console:**

> aws_s3_bucket.tf_s3
> ╷
> │ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
> │
> │   on  line 1:
> │   (source code not available)
> │
> │ A managed resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tf_s3" has not been declared in the root module.

**Go Test Error: Getting this error even after "terraform apply" and buckets are successfully created**
--- FAIL: TestS3 (148.65s)
output.go:19:
Error Trace:    ***/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest@v0.41.24/modules/terraform/output.go:19
***/Terraform/AWS_S3_TF/tests/s3_test.go:24
Error:          Received unexpected error:
FatalError{Underlying: error while running command: exit status 1;
Error: Output "tf_s3_name" not found

```
                            The output variable requested could not be found in the state file. If you
                            recently added this to your configuration, be sure to run `terraform apply`,
                            since the state won't be updated with new output variables until that command
                            is run.}
            Test:           TestS3
```

FAIL
exit status 1

**Expected:**
I want to get all attributes of "aws_s3_bucket.tf_s3" for both dev and stage.
And then execute them against go test.

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Please post the entire error message to the question.

Comment: @MarkoE Added the details. Please let me know if anything required to get this working.  Thank you.

Comment: What module is being tested by `terratest` as `TerraformDir: "../"` is unclear?